# Proof of Linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T$ be a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself.  For a given vector $v$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, if $T(v)\neq 0$ but $T^2(v) = T(T(v)) = 0$, then prove that $v$ and $T(v)$ are linearly independent.

I'm stumped on this problem.

Comment: Write down what happen if $v$ and $T(v)$ were dependant and then apply $T$ to the relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose, for a contradiction, $T(v)$ and $v$ are dependent. Then $T(v)=cv$ where $c\neq0$ is some scalar. However, if this were true then $T(T(v))=T(cv)=cT(v)\neq 0$. This contradicts that $T(T(v))=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Supposse that $v$ and $Tv$ are linearly dependent, then
$$Tv=cv$$
for some constant c in $\mathbb{R}$\{0}. Then
$$T(Tv)=T(cv)=cTv$$
would not be zero because $c$ and $Tv$ are not zero. Contradiction, it follows that $v$ and $Tv$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

$$\alpha v+\beta T(v)=0 \underbrace{\implies}_{T(0)=0} \alpha T(v)+\beta T^2(v)=0 \underbrace{\implies}_{T^2(v)= 0} \alpha T(v)=0\underbrace{\implies}_{T(v)\ne  0} \alpha=0\implies \beta=0$$ from where we conclude that $v$ and $T(v)$ are linearly independet.